# Button to add additonal tabs in dojo TabContainer

Tags: javascript, dojo

Basically I have a JSP page where upon clicking the button it should make a new tab with the href set at whatever the ${submission.id} variable is. However clicking the button doesn't make any tabs. I've tried looking at dojo tutorials and reading documentation but I am lost on what my mistake is.

```
<script>
dojoConfig = {
    async : true,
    parseOnLoad : true
}
</script>
<script src="js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div id="tabPanel" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Home" data-dojo-props="selected: true">
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button"
onclick="registry.byId('tabPanel').addChild(new ContentPane({
title:'test',
closable:true,
href:'submissions/${submission.id}'
}), 6);">Details</button>
</div>
</div>
<script>
require([ //Layout and Menu
         "dojo/parser",
         "dojo/dom",
         "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
         "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
         "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
         "dijit/form/Button",
         "dojo/domReady!"
         ], function(parser) {
            parser.parse();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that is called in the `onclick` attribute does not have the references to the required modules.
You could try the following.

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button"
onclick="createTab();">Details</button>

<script>
function createTab(){
   require([ //registry and ContenPane
         "dijit/registry",
         "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
         ], function(registry,ContentPane) {

            registry.byId('tabPanel')
            .addChild(new ContentPane({
                 title:'test',
                 closable:true,
                 href:'submissions/${submission.id}'
              }),6);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page doesn't seem to actually have a widget with an id of `tabPanel`.  Your TabContainer has the *class* `tabPanel`, but it'd need to also have the *id* `tabPanel` for your `registry.byId` call to find it.

Comment: I changed class to id="tabPanel" and it still doesn't work.